# @@ROWCOUNT check not detecting zero row count

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server Stored Procedure (using SQL Server 2008 R2) where it performs several different table updates. When rows have been updated I want to record information in an Audit table.

Here is my pseudo code:

```
UPDATE tblName SET flag = 'Y' WHERE flag = 'N'

IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO auditTable...etc
END
```

Unfortunately, even when zero rows are updated it still records the action in the audit table.

Note: There are no related triggers on the table being updated.

Any ideas why this could be happening?

Comment: This looks fine. Something else must be going on. This is obviously not your real code. What have you left out? Add `PRINT @@ROWCOUNT` immediately after the update statement.

Comment: Probably you have another statement between your `UPDATE` and `IF @@ROWCOUNT` that resets it.

Comment: Add SELECT @@ROWCOUNT befor your IF to see what is the result.

Comment: Strangely, it does return 0 when I put PRINT @@ROWCOUNT after the update statement. The audit record does a CAST(@@ROWCOUNT AS varchar(10)) (because it is part of a user-friendly message) - maybe when the @@ROWCOUNT is > 0 the cast messes it up. Confusing...

Comment: Show your actual code. Not "pseudo code"

Comment: What if is suggested that you are pointing to the wrong database in SSMS?

Do this </br>

SELECT count(*) from tablename where flag="Y";<br/>
UPDATE tblName SET flag = 'Y' WHERE flag = 'N';      <br/>
SELECT count(*) from tablena,e where flag="Y";<br/>
 
is the count different?

Comment: sorry apparently I don't know how to format comments yet.

Answer (score 6):

Any statement that is executed in T-SQL will set the `@@rowcount`, even the `if` statement, so the general rule is to capture the value in the statement following the statement you're interested in.

So after

```
update table set ....
```

you want

```
Select @mycount = @@Rowcount
```

Then you use this value to do your flow control or messages.

[As the docs state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187316.aspx), even a simple variable assignment will set the `@@rowcount` to 1.

This is why it's important in this case that if you want people to diagnose the problem then you need to provide the actual code, not pseudo code.

Comment: +1 and here's an illustration of how 0-row updates might have been captured: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cf0d9/2. As can be seen, the OP's pattern doesn't capture *real* zero updates, whereas non-zero updates are recorded as zero ones, because `IF` affects (sets to 0) the `@@ROWCOUNT` result even after reading it.